# Get line and file of opengl errors

Tags: java, debugging, opengl, lwjgl

So I was changing a few things with framebuffers and got a few opengl errors.

Would there be any way to log the line and file or the error as well as make a breakpoint?

in java ( using lwjgl)

Answer (score 1):

1. Request a [debug context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Debug_contexts) from the OS
2. [Enable debug output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output#Enabling_Debug_Output) with `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT)`
3. Register a [debug message callback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output#Getting_messages) with `glDebugMessageCallback()`
4. Enable synchronous callball execution with `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS)`
5. Set a breakpoint in the callback and/or add logging to it.

Comment: I made a function and it gave me some extra details, but the breakpoint isn't working.